# how intersect query works in sugar ORM

Tags: java, android, sugarorm

```
 Select PRODUCT from PRODUCT_TAGS where TAGS = 1 intersect Select PRODUCT from PRODUCT_TAGS where TAGS = 5
```

the above used to fetch the products which has the ID 1,5 only. i was able to fetch the data when i run it in db browser . can someone tell me whether it is possible to execute the query in the sugar ORM data base.

Answer (score 0):

SugarORM has [a query builder](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/query.html), but it doesn't support insersect.

You can however run queries manually using `findWithQuery(<SQL>, <params>)`:

```
List<ProductTags> products = ProductTags.findWithQuery(ProductTags.class, "Select PRODUCT from PRODUCT_TAGS where TAGS = ? intersect Select PRODUCT from PRODUCT_TAGS where TAGS = ?, "1", "5");
```

Comment: List<ProductTags> products = ProductTags.findWithQuery(ProductTags.class, "Select PRODUCT from PRODUCT_TAGS where TAGS = ? intersect Select PRODUCT from PRODUCT_TAGS where TAGS = ?","1","5");

Comment: this query returns size =0 for me. may i know the reason why am getting this

Comment: Ensure the table and column names are correct. You can also try doing `SugarRecord.findWithQuery`. Also, try doing `SELECT * FROM...`

Comment: table names are correct .even i tried whatever u have mentioned above still it returns size =0.is there any other way to do ?

Comment: when i run the same query db browser it return the value

Comment: Could you not just do `WHERE TAGS = "1" OR TAGS = "5"` to avoid using the intersect at all? This could be done with the [query builder](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/query.html).